# Failed to find mapViewStyle using sherlock

Tags: android, styles, android-mapview

in my application mapview was working fine but suddenly one day when i just wrote the xml file the error is not going even changing the the target sdk, cleaning rebuilding and also deleting the R.java file. Also changed styles.xml file to Theme.Light but still error is shown. Here is my xml for mapView and also the manifest file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".WAmIActivity" >

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:apiKey="0dtHyV-rxfPOpVnbG700kdJIIx3DIxRid59K_mg"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</RelativeLayout>

Manifest file :-

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mygooglemapactivity"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/SherlockTheme" >


        <uses-library
            android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>


       <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainScreenActivity"
            android:label="MainScreenActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

The key been officially losted and no updates for google map v1.Use Google map v2.

Please refer the site.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/intro

Comment: Ok let me try that but tell me one thing will it solve the problem which am facing, because am just have to add v4.jar file. And it says the problem is with styles.xml which is built in MapView i.e.,mapViewStyle if am not wrong. Please help.